# swap columns with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to swap these two columns:

```
khushboo    खुशबू
khushbuu    खुशबू
khushbu खुशबू
khusbhu खुशबू
tera    तेरा
teraa   तेरा
thera   तेरा
teraaa  तेरा
badan   बदन
sulgeh  सुलगे
sulage  सुलगे
sulge   सुलगे
mehke   महके
mahake  महके
```

I know I can read these columns with pandas using like `dataset = pd.read_csv('/file.txt', delimeter ='\t', encoding='utf-8')` and even split dataset into two parts using `dataset.iloc[:0]` and `dataset.iloc[:-1]`.
but how can I swap them and create a new csv or text file? I tried `pd.to_csv` but don't know how to pass the arguments, I always get a list in return.
I want it to look like this:

```
तेरा tera
तेरा terra
तेरा thera
```

Just want to swap these columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('/file.txt', delimeter ='\t', encoding='utf-8')
dataset = dataset[[dataset.columns[1], dataset.columns[0]]]
dataset.to_csv("file.csv", sep=" ", index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the first column header is `khushboo` and the second column header is 
 `खुशबू`

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('/file.txt', delimeter ='\t', encoding='utf-8')
dataset = dataset[['खुशबू','khushboo']]
dataset.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)  #you may also have to pass `encoding='utf-8'` again.
```

Comment: dataset becomes a list with those two elements? `dataset.to_csv` won't run because its a list now and don't have `.to_csv` attribute. I printed dataset, only two elements now.

Comment: @Mel see updated answer... this basic one throws me off sometimes too...

Comment: my first comment was for ur edited post. it doesn't work

Comment: I edited my post after you commented.... try it again... Again, I have made assumptions as to what your headers are. Replace the text with your actual headers in the order that you want them.

Comment: its almost working. it prints `तेरा,tera` I want space between them not ","